# Get request outside a controller in .netcore

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way I can get the response from a method without using a controller. I mean, in order to get the tenants from the database I use attribute binding and I get it from: "http://localhost:5000/api/tenants". Is there a way I can retrieve values without using a controller, like a service? For example in angular I use httpclient to get the response. Is there anything similar in .netcore 2 webapi? Thank, you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Controller`, it uses `UseMvc middleware` to route the request to controller.

If you would not use controller, you could try custom middleware to return the data directly based on the request path.

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //your config
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       //your config
        app.Map("/tenants", map => {
            map.Run(async context => {
                var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MVCProContext>();
                var tenants = await dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tenants));
            });
        }); 
        app.Run(async context => {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Default response");
        });          
    }
}
```